# Pivotal TC Server starting, but website built using Spring not loading (was before)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller, server

So a while back I started a basic Spring MVC project. It was working fine, then randomly stopped. The server itself starts up, but when I go to visit the website it won't load anymore. Here's what it says in the logs of the server (which doesn't seem too useful):

```
Oct 23, 2015 8:17:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2180 ms
Oct 23, 2015 8:17:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3190 ms
```

I followed this tutorial by the way: http://www.programcreek.com/2014/02/spring-mvc-helloworld-using-maven-in-eclipse/

Here's my dispatcher-servlet.xml that's in my WEB-INF folder:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.programcreek" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Here's my web.xml which is also in WEB-INF folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">


<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And finally, the [structure of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAkfe.png)

If there's anything else that's needed, let me know. I just can't see anything too obvious. Maybe I'm missing something?! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. I ended up removing my project from Spring then re-importing it.

That was after a couple hours of cleaning, using mvn clean, stop, start, publish, retarting spring, restart the computer...

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue when i was using pivotal server. pivotal server was not giving proper logs. I have used tomcat and found that some of dependencies got corrupted. so I have removed .m2 folder and again run mvn clean install -DSkipTests. Problem got solved.